# Copying a part of fullpath variable and use that part to construct another different fullpath variable in shell

Tags: regex, shell

I have one variable var1='common_location/specific_location_1/common_filename_text' now I have to get a new variable var2='common_location/specific_location_2/common_filename_text'.
How can I do it in a linux shell. I am novice in shell scripting. So please explain assuming I know a very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that:

```
var2=${var1/1/2}
```

where `var1` is variable with `/specific_location_1/common_filename_text` stored in it.
Below you can see that `var1` and `var2` differs only with one symbol

```
var1='common_location/specific_location_1/common_filename_text'
var2='common_location/specific_location_2/common_filename_text'
```

So we need just to substitute 1 to 2 and get new variable you need.
You can do it with :

```
var2=${var1/1/2}
```

Pretty easy.

Comment: please explain what is 'var','_1' and '_2'

Comment: sorry, it was mistype with `var`. Should be `var1`. And explanation is in the answer right now.